# How to prevent a slide from becoming blurry when moving to next slide?

Tags: deck.js

I'd like to prevent a specific slide of my deck to become blurry when moving to next slide.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default themes, incrementally displayed elements that are not active anymore are made half-opaque (blurry). You can thus force a given element to be always fully opaque.

For example, you can replace :

```
<div class="slide">should stay opaque</div>
```

by

```
<div class="slide" style="opacity: 1.0" >should stay opaque</div>
```

Alternatively, if you are used to CSS, you can also modify the stylesheet and for example add a class "stay" to your element and, in your CSS:

```
.stay { opacity: 1.0 !important; }
```